# i am unable to get the user id via context api after login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

i created a login page which will post request on the `/auth/login` route in my backend express server after my backend server verifies the user the page will navigate on this route `/auth/profile/${userId}` using useNavigate, this route will get the user information from the database the URL is showing that I am getting the id from backend but when I am using context API to fetch user details it is showing that the userId is undefined in the route how I get the user id first to get the request in my context API

> loginUser function

```
const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, password } = login;
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
        email,
        password,
      });
      const { userId } = response.data;
      setUserId(userId);
       console.log(`hi i am login page the user id is ${userId}`);
      if (login.error) {
        toast.error(login.error);
      } else {
        setLogin({});
        toast.success('Login Successful. Welcome!');

        // Use the updated userId here
        navigate(`/auth/profile/${userId}`);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

> contextApi

```
  import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios"
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UseContextProvider({children , userId}) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`/auth/profile/${userId}`)
                setUser(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching user details:", error);
            }
        }
        fetchUserDetails();
    }, [userId])
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
          {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
      );
};
```

> Backend -- loginUser Function

```
 const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        if (!email || !password) {
            return res.json({ message: 'Please enter all the details' })
        }
        //check if the user already exist or not
        const userExist = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (!userExist) {
            return res.json({ message: 'Wrong credentials' })
        }
        // check password match
        const isPasswordMatched = await comparePassword(password, userExist.password);
        if (!isPasswordMatched) {
            return res.json({ message: 'Wrong credentials pass' });
        }
        const token = await jwt.sign({ id: userExist._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE,
        })
        return res
            .cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true })
            .json({ success: true, message: 'LoggedIn Successfully', userId: userExist._id });
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ error: error });
    }
};
```

> getProfile function

```
    const getProfile = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne();
        if (!user) {
            return res.json({ message: 'No user found' })
        }
        return res.json({ user: user})
    } catch (error) {
        return res.json({ error: error });
    }
};
```

> isAuthenticated Middleware

```
    const isAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization;

        if (!token) {
            return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized: No token provided' });
        }

        jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                // Handle token verification failure
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized: Invalid token' });
            }

            // Check if the token has expired
            if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
                return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized: Token has expired' });
            }

            // Retrieve user information from the database using the user ID from the token
            req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
            next();
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle other errors
        return next(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any route `/auth/profile/${userId}` in your frontend (like to display anything). And instead of using `useEffect` to get again the user details you can set the user details once the user is authenticated and logged in. And kindly point out where the `userId` gets `undefined`.

Comment: no there is no route in my front end to display anything, all components are wrapped in the contextapi, and when the page navigating to the profile page i am getting undefined on the place of userId since context does not have user id so its unable to hit the backend api in backend server , for your convenience i have created the gist link for you please check and get back thank you for your help : https://gist.github.com/nikhilkcodes/5d02fb45c6ff640e43ec0c3991b4e936

Comment: also i want to add that you can solve my query here thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a state for `userId` to initaite the `useEffect` hook.

```
//context.jsx
export function UseContextProvider({children}) {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
         try {
           const response = await axios.get(`/auth/profile/${userId}`)
           setUser(response.data);
         } catch (error) {
           console.error("Error fetching user details:", error);
         }
      }
      fetchUserDetails();
    }, [userId])
    return (
        //pass the setuserId state and if needed also pass the userId
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, userId, setUser, setUserId }}> 
          {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Remove the separate state that is maintained in the `LoginForm.jsx`, instead utilize the state from the `context.jsx`.

```
//LoginForm.jsx
const Loginform = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    //remove this state
    const { setUserId } = React.useContext(UserContext);
    const [login, setLogin] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    })

    const loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = login;
        try {
          const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
            email,
            password,
          });
          const { userId } = response.data;
          setUserId(userId); //setUserId from context.jsx
          if (login.error) {
            toast.error(login.error);
          } else {
            setLogin({});
            toast.success('Login Successful. Welcome!');
            navigate(`/auth/profile/${userId}`);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
}
```

This will update the `userId` and trigger the `useEffect` in the context Provider to fetch the user details.